# Change ownership of file during copy

Tags: unix, copy

How to change the ownership of a file during copy itself. I mean in `cp` command how to add ownership

I cant rely on `--preserve` and copying the file and then changing the ownership of file due to some constraints.
Thanks

Comment: why can't you simply apply the new ownership after copying?

Comment: maybe `install` ?

Answer (score 10):

As stated here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124855/move-files-and-change-ownership-at-the-sametime

Use rsync(1):

```
rsync \
  --remove-source-files \
  --chown=wanteduser:wantedgroup \
    /home/oldfolder /home/newfolder
```

Comment: Cool solution, faithfully copy/pasted from the cited source. However the OP wanted to _copy_ and set ownership, not _move_. You will need to remove the `--remove-source-files`. I also needed to add `-og` to make it work (see section on `--usermap` in the rsync man page).

Answer (score 4):

Not a direct answer to your question, but if you've got GNU `cpio` available, you can use it (in copy-pass mode) to copy files while changing ownership. eg.

```
echo 'some_file_name' | cpio -p --owner someuser:somegroup destination_directory
```

Comment: Using cpio -p  works as long as some_file_name is in $CWD. If a path is included, cpio will try to tack on the whole path at the destination, which is probably not what the OP wanted?

Answer (score 2):

Not easily. You could perhaps run the `cp` command as the user you want to own the new file, or copy it sideways to a temporary location, `chown` it then copy it to where it wants to get, but `cp` itself lacks `chown`.

Answer (score 2):

I make use of a workaround with command "scp":

```
scp -p file.txt <user>@localhost:<destination>
```

example:

```
scp -p /home/reportuser/dailyReport.doc root@localhost:/root/dailyReports/20150105/
```

-p is for preserving source file timestamp